# Return two rows for each row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table I wish to return two rows from each row. The transaction table has one row for each transaction. I would like to return the transaction date and amount in journal entry format below:

```
TransactionDate  TransactionRef      Transaction Amount
  01/01/2019       12345                   500.5
```

I also need to include a debit/credit column to have the first row post as a positive amount with the debit/credit displaying 'Db' then the second row returned will be negative with a debit/credit displaying 'Cr'

I need to query the Transaction table and return below values:

```
TransactionDate  TransactionRef      Transaction Amount      Db/Cr
  01/01/2019       12345                   500.5              Db
  01/01/2019       12345                   -500.5             Cr
```

Comment: Are the values always positive in the original table?

Comment: The values in original table can be positive and negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UNION ALL:

```
select 
  *,
  case when TransactionAmount > 0 then 'Db' else 'Cr' end AS [Db/Cr] 
from tablename
union all
select 
  TransactionDate,  
  TransactionRef,
  -1.0 * TransactionAmount,
  case when TransactionAmount > 0 then 'Cr' else 'Db' end
from tablename
order by TransactionDate, TransactionRef, TransactionAmount desc
```

Comment: Thanks all. I am using Sami's solutions as I found a couple records with negative Transaction Amounts. I had to expand the CASE Statement and now getting two rows on Db and one Cr. Much thanks to the communities quick response and skill with this solution.

Comment: Not intentionally. Must have inadvertently clicked while working on other monitor.

Answer (score 3):

Just another option is a Cross Apply

```
 Select A.TransactionDate
       ,A.TransactionRef
       ,B.TransactionAmount
       ,DrCr  = case when sign(B.TransactionAmount)<0 then 'Cr' else 'Dr' end
 From   YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( TransactionAmount)
                     ,( TransactionAmount*-1)
             ) B(TransactionAmount)
```

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the grin.  Had my Wheaties today.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
  coalesce(t1.transactiondate,t2.transactiondate) as transdate, 
  coalesce(t1.transactionref,t2.transactionref) as transref,    
  coalesce(t1.transactionamount,-1*ABS(t2.transactionamount)) as transamount  
from tansaction t1 full outer join transaction t2 
on 1 = 0 
order by 
  TransactionRef, 
  transactiondate,    
  SIGN(t1.transactionamount)desc,
  ABS(t2.transactionamount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union query:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, TransactionRef, [Transaction Amount], 'Db' AS [Db/Cr]
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT TransactionDate, TransactionRef, -1.0*[Transaction Amount], 'Cr'
FROM yourTable;
```

The idea here is the second half of the above union query generates the same record, but with the negative of the transaction amount, along with `Cr` as the label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` and do 2 selects from your transaction table.

```
SELECT TransactionDate,  TransactionRef,      [Transaction Amount], 'Db' AS [Db/Cr] from table

UNION ALL 

SELECT TransactionDate,  TransactionRef,      [Transaction Amount] * -1, 'Cr' AS [Db/Cr] from table
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are always positive in the original table, I would use a variation of John's solution:

```
select t.TransactionDate, t.TransactionRef, v.drcr, v.TransactionAmount
from t Cross Apply
     ( values ('Cr', TransactionAmount),
              ('Dr', - TransactionAmount)
     ) v(drcr, TransactionAmount);
```